# How can I config the same behavior in nginx ingress controller as in nginx?

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

In nginx, I've got some configuration like this:

```
    location /admingateway/ {
       proxy_pass      http://localhost:8001/admingateway/;

       proxy_set_header        Host                    $host:$proxy_port;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        Via                     "nginx";   
 }
```

My question is how can I configure the same behavior in my ingress yaml for the 4 header settings?

Comment: did your nginx config work in K8s?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator haven't actually tried it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the

> nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet

Annotation in order to add custom Nginx configuration

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: nginxconfigsnippet
    annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
         location /admingateway/ {
       proxy_pass      http://localhost:8001/admingateway/;

       proxy_set_header        Host                    $host:$proxy_port;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        Via                     "nginx";   
 }
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
.
.
.
```

[Source](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet)